# ConfigurationProperites not applied in SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

We have the following configuration properties class (reduced the minimum)

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
data class MyConfiguraion(
    val mapping: MutableMap<String, Map<String, Int>>
)
```

The configuration in the application yaml looks like this:

```
prefix.mapping:
   value1: 
     a: 1
     b: 2
```

using the application.yml, the map is passed correctly, though if I want to test it with `SpringBootTest`, the map is not passed, instead an empty map is passed to the constructor:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [MyConfiguraion::class, ],
    properties = [
        "prefix.mapping.value1.a=1",
        "prefix.mapping.value1.b=2",

    ]
)
internal class CapabilityMappingTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var config: MyConfiguraiton

    @Test
    fun `mapping was correctly appiled`() {

        expectThat(config)
            .get { mapping }.and {
                get("value1")
                    .isNotNull()
                    .and {
                        get("a") isEqualTo 1
                        get("b") isEqualTo 2
       
            }
    }
}
```

(Example is reduced to a minimum to show the issue. Without the context, it does not look useful)

Comment: With your setup you are loading `MyConfiguration`  as the configuration disabling all the auto configurations etc. Remove the `classes` attribute and it should work, drawback it will create a full context but that is needed to enable the configuration support.

Comment: that might go in the right direction, though when I dont want to start the whole application for this simple test, how can I make sure that only the ConfiguraitonProperty auto configuraiton is working

Comment: You will need to figure out which moving parts of Spring Boot are needed to make this work and manually configure them. But why do you want to test this in the first place? Aren't you trusting the Spring tests for this functionality (because that is basically what you are testing right now).

Comment: reuduced to the minimum, that only checks spring functionality. My original intention was to change the keys, as spring interprets e.g. `.` characters as hierarchcal terminator. My test was about checking if these transformations was working correctly, which failed as the mapping was not passed at all. In the meantime I know that spring supports escaping with `[` and `]`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@ConstructorBinding` in a `@ConfigurationProperties` class and you need to have it created by Spring in unit tests exactly like at runtime, in your test class you need to use `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` (`@EnableConfigurationProperties` won't work, unless I did something wrong...) and remove the class from the `classes` property of `@SpringBootTest`.

If the @ConfigurationProperties class is in a different package than the test class (and it isn't a child package of any depth, either), you need to specify the package like this for example: `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.example.the.package")`

Your example code should become like this:

@ConfigurationProperties class: unchanged.

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
data class MyConfiguraion(
    val mapping: MutableMap<String, Map<String, Int>>
)
```

Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    properties = [
        "prefix.mapping.value1.a=1",
        "prefix.mapping.value1.b=2",

    ]
)
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
internal class CapabilityMappingTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var config: MyConfiguraiton

    @Test
    fun `mapping was correctly appiled`() {

        expectThat(config)
            .get { mapping }.and {
                get("value1")
                    .isNotNull()
                    .and {
                        get("a") isEqualTo 1
                        get("b") isEqualTo 2
       
            }
    }
}
```

Again, this is assuming that the @ConfigurationProperties class is in the same package, or in a child package (at any depth) of the test class.